# iPhone/IOS NsKeyedArchiver / NSUserDefaults loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm very new to iOS programming. I'm trying to use the method listed below to loop through my archived object (nsuserdefaults) and display the content of it. I'm getting an error when I try to use the code below, the app crashes with:

```
-[NSUserDefaults objectEnumerator]: unrecognized selector sent
```

If anyone can help me out it would be great, I believe I'm looping through it improperly...

```
-(IBAction)loadNames:(id)sender {

NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", usertext.text];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

User * userr = [User alloc];
userr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileName];
NSUserDefaults * lg = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *encodedUser = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userr];
[lg setObject:encodedUser forKey:@"userr"];

NSEnumerator *e = [lg objectEnumerator];
while (lg = [e nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", usertext);

}
```

}